# Intersection and union as extreme solutions of set inclusions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working through the the "Families" chapter in "Naive Set Theory" by Paul Halmos, and found this note in the final exercise:

> Prove also (with appropriate provisos about empty families) that $\bigcap_i X_i \subset X_j \subset \bigcup_i X_i$ for each index $j$ and **that intersection and the union can in fact characterized as the
>   extreme solution of these inclusions** [emphasis mine]. This means that if  $X_j \subset Y$ for each index $j$, then $\bigcup_i X_i \subset Y$, and that $\bigcup_i X_i$ is the only set satisfying this minimality condition; the formulation for intersections is similar.

What does it mean to say that intersection and union are the "extreme solution of these inclusions"? The empty set $\emptyset$, for example, seems like a better candidate for the extreme solution on the left side of the inclusion relationship, and *any* set disjoint from any $X_j$ unioned in with the full union would increase the bounds.

Does it perhaps mean that these are the **tightest** possible bounds?

This exercise was also covered in [Exercise in Halmos set theory book.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470673/exercise-in-halmos-set-theory-book), but not this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the note isn't very clearly stated. What Halmos means is that $\bigcup_i X_i$ contains every $X_j$ and is contained in any other set $Y$ that contains every $X_j$. I.e., $\bigcup_i X_i$ is minimal amongst all sets $Y$ that contain every $X_j$.